# I want to get volume information from android

Tags: android

I want to get the volume information of notifications, media, ringtones, system and calls currently set in Android

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
private AudioManager mAudioManager;
mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
int media_max_volume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int media_min_volume = mAudioManager.getStreamMinVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int current_volume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

like Kumar Bibek said there is several stream types for your will.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. By using the AudioManager class.

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamVolume(int)

```
AudioManager.getStreamVolume(int streamType)
```

To get a specific value, you can pass in parameters for the `streamType`. Following are the options available.

```
STREAM_VOICE_CALL
STREAM_SYSTEM
STREAM_RING
STREAM_MUSIC
STREAM_ALARM
STREAM_NOTIFICATION
STREAM_DTMF
STREAM_ACCESSIBILITY
```